# For a React app, can it be made so that `npm run build` will bust the cache for CSS files?

Tags: reactjs

The current React has the tool to create an app:

```
create-react-app hello-world
```

and to build the app to be deployed:

```
npm run build
```

It busts the cache for the main JavaScript file, using a filename like `main.742a4123.js`, but when I tried the app, the CSS file might not get refreshed and I can disable the cache in the Chrome DevTools, but what about the general users?

They can be using the old version.  Maybe the server can be configured so that the `etag` or expiration date can make it refresh the file, but if the file can be `style.css?t=1491264234` or `style.742a4123.css` then there is no need to do such checks and worry about what if the file expires in 1 day but you need to push out a new version as a fix after 2 hours.  Does `npm run build` have some mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For your production builds, you may need to eject (npm run eject) to get the webpack file and edit it to use [chunkhash] in the output file name. For more details:
https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95

Comment: so it cannot be automatic (yet)? If it can do that for the main.js, doing it for the CSS file shouldn't be that hard...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution for you how to busted the cache in below given link

[Strategies for cache busting CSS](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

So the question you want 'npm run build' will bust the cache?
But first thing is if you are using the create react app which wont give much option for bundling script (so can't say no but there is lot of configuration) but the issue that script lie in node_module so any update to it wont help

Second option is you eject the reacts-script by run this command '**npm run eject**' then you'll find a config folder created in your project. You will find your webpack config files init.

Incase if you don't want to eject and you just want to look at the config you will find them in /node_modules/react-scripts/config

```
webpack.config.dev.js. //used by `npm start`
webpack.config.prod.js //used by `npm run build`
```

Once you have your own webpack config file you will able to name the css file unique and add that file to html for more please read webpack config

[Here is webpack tutorial which will help you more](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a React environment variable, assign a unique value to it and reference it in your index.html file.

In your build script (bash):

```
REACT_APP_CACHE_BUST={e.g. build number from a CI tool} npm run build
```

In your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/index.css?cachebust=%REACT_APP_CACHE_BUST%" />
```

The variable name has to start with REACT_APP_.
More about environment variables in React: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables.